# Unable to create a cluster in databricks on a customer managed vpc (private link enabled) - AWS

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks, aws-private-link

I’m trying to create a cluster in databricks in a customer managed vpc (AWS) environment. Created both front end and back end endpoints. The cluster got terminated with message ‘NPIP tunnel setup failure.’ Looking at the logs, it throws wait for Ngork tunnel failure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you aren't blocking outgoing traffic to the Databricks control plane.  The section "Firewall appliance infrastructure" [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/aws/customer-managed-vpc.html) describes that you need to enable traffic to following objects (this list may change over the time):

- Databricks web application
- Databricks secure cluster connectivity (SCC) relay (ngrok)
- AWS S3 global URL
- AWS S3 regional URL
- AWS STS global URL
- AWS STS regional URL
- AWS Kinesis regional URL
- Table metastore RDS regional URL

Actual global & regional host names could be found in the [following table](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/aws/customer-managed-vpc.html#required-data-plane-addresses) in the same documentation